# Json module not found vue.js using webpack

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to import a JSON file into my `main.js` file using this:

```
import json from 'json/data.json'
```

Here is my JSON loader and I have also included the loader configurations:

```
{
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json'  
 }
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

> ERROR in ./src/main.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
>   'json/data.json' in C:\pathto\project\src  @ ./src/main.js 27:12-37

Comment: Is the json folder in same directory as main.js file?

Comment: yes the folder is in the same directory

Comment: use a relative path like this: `import json from './json/data.json'`

Comment: ERROR in ./src/json/data.json
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token       in JSON at position 1283
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.module.exports 
now it is giving me this

Comment: check if your json is valid using a json validator

Comment: i don't know how to check that but it is not in my packaage.json

Comment: i have validated my json file using https://jsonlint.com/ and now it is not giving me any error

Comment: but its saying error in JSON

Comment: now it is working can you tell how to display data using the exact file

Comment: open a new question so others can also help...the doibt you have now and the question does not match at all

Comment: okay thank you very much